# Does 'precious little' take more than one function?

Tags: modifiers, fused-determiner

> "You can't blame them," said Dumbledore gently. "We've had **precious little** to celebrate for eleven years." (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> There's **precious little** left. [(thefreedictionary.com)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precious)
>
> He had **precious little** right to complain [(thefreedictionary.com)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precious)

It looks like the first and second ‘precious little’ seem to be noun phrases, while the third one is an adjective phrase. How do you parse them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have parsed them correctly. Quantifiers like *little*, *much*, *few*, *most*, *many* can also be used as nouns; and when they are used this way, any modifiers which each licenses may be 'carried with' them:

> We have precious few choices ... Precious few are left.
>   There are exceedingly many dragons here ... Exceedingly many would agree with you.
>   He has quite a little money ... Quite a little was left unsaid.
>   I've got entirely too much homework ... This is entirely too much to endure.

You have to be careful though: different quantifiers license different modifiers. I've never encountered *precious* with *many* or *much*.

Comment: hmmm, 'quite a little ...?' that's unnatural (without context).  You get away with the 'money' example coz 'a little money' is a thing, but I can't work out whether the information provided was all smoke and mirrors or very comprehensive in the 'left unsaid' example.

Comment: @mcalex *quite little* is 'very little'; *quite **a** little*  is 'much'. I'm not making it up: see [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/little) and [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/quite%20a%20little).

Comment: Oh, ok. Wow. So it was smoke and mirrors.  Must be that understatement trick the Brits love.  I haven't heard it used down under - but then again, we do say 'quite a bit' quite a bit, to the extent that I had to re-remember that 'bit' is tiny in other contexts.  +1 for the edification.

Comment: @mcalex My own lexicon is sort of mid-Atlantic, so it may be a Brit thing. Note that the 'admirative' use of *quite a little* is different: "That's quite a little layout ya got there, bud".

Comment: To this British ear, both those examples for *quite a little* sound decidedly dated. I'm more used to things like *"I met up with a few of the guys in the pub after work, and before long we had **quite a little** party going"*. Where it's just the literal sense of *a bit of*, with all the "exaggeration" taken care of by the choice of a "spectacular" noun following. Then there's "set phrases" like when Mom catches daughter playing with her make-up: *"Quite the little madam, aren't we?"*